# phpstorm and qt shared memory segment leak

Tags: linux, qt, phpstorm

I have problems with qt apps after some time of using phpstorm.
If I try to open new qt app or dialog window from any qt application I get these errors:

```
QNativeImage: Unable to attach to shared memory segment. 
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
```

if I shut down phpstorm or restart it everything is ok. After some time I see these errors, not just after openning phpstorm. I try to close any other apps except phpstorm. Problem goes away only after closing phpstorm.
What is possible wrong?

Comment: If you will get no answers try https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new (but provide more info (like your OS, java and IDE versions etc) and not just error description).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing OpenJDK to OracleJDk helps me.
In archlinux find and install oraclejdk and change default java envirement (or delete openjdk)

Answer (score 0):

Installing OracleJDK ( :'-( ) helped here too (on debian testing - stretch/sid) both with keepassx (which is qt based app) and PHPStorm.

I followed these steps for OracleJDK installation: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can set:

```
QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=native
```

Add in your `.bashrc` or `.profile`:

```
export QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=native
```

This problem seems to be wide spread on [Arch Linux](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=200167). I can reproduce this problem with any Qt application when a Java Swing application is running.